# Where do Entities get saved if you run a GAE project in development mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, jdo

I am running a GWT Web Application project in Eclipse with certain Entities that I make persisent using JDO. Where (on my file system) do these Entities actually get saved if I run the project in development mode from Eclipse (so not on the Google App Engine, but locally)?

Comment: My guess : war/you_project_name/...

Comment: Title and tagging is all misleading. This is AppEngine specific, not GWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already look up in you eclipse Work_dir? If there isn´t any of the entities you search, maybe you will find something helpful with window-->preferences-->GWT.

But unfortunately I never worked with GWT, so I´m just guessing.